# How to convert string date value to long date value using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

This is json code:

```
{
  "Account": {
    "Account name": "Filrefly",
    "Date" : "2018-09-20"
  }
}
```

I need Final output like this

```
{ 
  "Account": { 
    "Account name": "Firefly",
    "Date": 20180920
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.Account.{
"Account name": $.Accountname,
"Date":$number(($toMillis($.Date))~>$fromMillis('[Y][M][D]'))
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).